# Is there an XML tag in the C# comment syntax that allows for a section of text to be ignored by comment generators?

Tags: c#, comments, sandcastle

Does anyone know if there is an XML comment tag that allows one to hide text from a comment generator (specifically sandcastle)?

For example,  given the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the sum of two numbers.
/// </summary>
/// <hide>I do not want this text in any documentation generated by sandcastle.</hide>
/// <param name="a">The first number.</param>
/// <param name="b">The second number.</param>
/// <returns>A value representing the sum of two numbers.</returns>
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
 return a + b;
}
```

I would like to have the text between the  ...  tags not show up in any sandcastle generated output.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Then don't put /// in front of it?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; that is actually what I am going now; but it is tedious when the comment template is auto-generated by a tool like ghostdoc (I have to break of the comment scheme/flow).  I was hoping for a more 'elegant' solution that would fit into the traditional xml comment scheme.